# Why this split function does not work?

Tags: c++, input, split

I was creating a function, it should split the `input1` in a `function` string (which contains the 1st word of `input1`) and in a `arguments` string (which contains the rest of `input1`). If i try to print the `function` string and the `arguments` string, they appear empty.

What should i do?

```
void split (string input1, string function, string arguments){

    bool args = false;

    string undefined;

    for (int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++){

        if (input1[i] == ' '){
            if (i == 0) {
                input1.erase(0, 1);
            } else if (i == (input1.length() - 1)){
                input1.erase((input1.length() - 1), 1);
            } else {
                if (!args) {
                    for (int o = 0; o < undefined.length(); o++)
                        function.push_back(undefined[o]);
                    args = true;
                } else if (args) {
                    for (int u = 0; u < undefined.length(); u++)
                        arguments.push_back(undefined[u]);
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (i == (input1.length() - 1)){
                undefined.push_back(input[i]);
                if (!args)
                    for (int u = 0; u < undefined.length(); u++)
                        function.push_back(undefined[u]);
                else
                    for (int e = 0; e < undefined.length(); e++)
                        arguments.push_back(undefined[e]);
            } else {
                undefined.push_back(input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider removing the c tag as this question seems to be about C++.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Why do I have a sneaky suspicion that this seems overly complicated just to extract words out of a string?  Why the calls to `erase`?

Comment: Why didn't you simply use `std::istringstream` and `operator >>` to extract the words?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie possibly because you don't know the exact wording of the task given to the students?

Comment: @BodoThiesen -- Well if they're using `string` and `vector`, I don't see how using `istringstream` would be harmful.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Did you read the actual task that was given to 
Edoardo La Greca?

Comment: Yes I read it.  I still say that 90% of what was written could have been eliminated if istringstream and operator >> were used.

Comment: To MrEricSir, Borgleader, πάντα ῥεῖ, Captain Giraffe, Olaf: The problem was clearly stated: The returned strings appear empty. The reason was visible in the first line of the posted code.

Comment: @Edoardo: Maybe you should rephrase the subject of the question, maybe to something like »function supposed to return two string always return empty strings« or so. Because »Why this split function does not work?« doesn't help anyone finding this question if he has a similar problem.

Comment: @BodoThiesen thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer: This answer assumes, you're using `std::string`.

```
void split (string input1, string function, string arguments){
```

When this function is called like this

```
string a = "input";
string b;
string c;

split(a, b, c);
```

Then you are essentially passing *copies* of `a`, `b` and `c` to the function `split` (`b` and `c` being empty at that point). In order for function `split` to be able to modify those you have two options:

1. Use pointers:

   ```
   void split (string input1, string * function, string * arguments) {
       [...]
   }
   split(a, &b, &c);
   ```
2. Use references:

   ```
   void split (string input1, string & function, string & arguments) {
       [...]
   }
   split(a, b, c);
   ```

Option 2 hides the fact, that `b` and `c` of the caller will be modified, but is easier to implement, because in option 1 you would have to either change all uses of `function` or `arguments` to `*function` or `*arguments` or you would have to add a second reference initialisation like this (what I would prefer anyway, because it stops you from hiding the fact, that you're going to modify those params):

```
void split (string input1, string * _function, string * _arguments) {
    string & function = _function;
    string & arguments = _arguments;
    [...]
}
```

> Depending on the actual task given to you, the function `split` might be implemented much easier than how you did it. One hint was given by [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) to use `std::istringstream` and it's `operator >>` to extract the words.

Comment: How does option 2 hide the fact that the values could be modified?  That is what lvalue references are for.  Also I would make option 2, option 1, as it is easier to deal with references.

Comment: @NathanOliver in the calling code, `split(a, b, c);` is not distinguishable from `split(a, b, c);` but it IS distinguishable from `split(a, &b, &c);`